# Adding points to an existing geometry

Tags: geometry, 2d, coordinates, autocad, autolisp

I have the dxf file of a 2D geometry created in AutoCAD and I would like to add points on the lines of the existing geometry. The list of points to be added is present in a text file.
[image]

For example, I want to add 10 points on the line between 3 and 2 in the above image. The(x,y) coordinates of the 10 points are present in a text file. Is there a way to import and snap the coordinates close to the boundary(/line) because the coordinates come from a pre-processing step and might lie a bit off from the actual points on 3 - 2.

Any suggestions will be of great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly it would be something like this:

```
 (defun C:ImportPoints (  / path coordinates askForFile loadPoints draw
 *error* )  (defun *error* ( msg / ) 
     (if (not (null msg ) ) (progn (princ "\nC:ImportPoints:*error*: " ) (princ msg ) (princ "\n")  ) )
 )
  (defun askForFile (  / 
      *error* ) (defun *error* ( msg / ) 
          (if (not (null msg ) )    (progn (princ "\naskForFile:*error*: " ) (princ msg ) (princ "\n")  ) )
      )
      (getfiled "Select the file with coordinates" "txt" 2)
  )

  (defun loadPoints ( path / 
      *error* ) (defun *error* ( msg / ) 
          (if (not (null msg ) )    (progn (princ "\nLoadPoints:*error*: " ) (princ msg ) (princ "\n")  ) )
      )  

    (setq filedesc (open Path "r"))
    (if filedesc(progn 
        (setq OutList (list))
        (setq linia(read-line filedesc))
        (while linia
        (progn
            (setq OutList (append OutList (list linia)))
            (setq linia (read-line filedesc))
        ))
        (close filedesc )
    ))  
    OutList
  )

  (defun draw ( coordinates / 
      *error* ) (defun *error* ( msg / ) 
          (if (not (null msg ) )    (progn (princ "\ndraw:*error*: " ) (princ msg ) (princ "\n")    ) )
      )
      (setq lastOSMODE (getvar "OSMODE"))
      (setvar "OSMODE" 512) ; 512 nearest
      (foreach % coordinates
        (command "_POINT" %)
      )
      (setvar "OSMODE" lastOSMODE ) ; ensure You didn't change anything in user settings
  )   


 (setq path (askForFile) )
 (setq coordinates (LoadPoints path) )
 (draw coordinates)
```

)

You have to know this is the basic "skeleton" of functionality. Main functions You have to use are:

`(getfiled ...)` - which let You select the file

`(setvar "OSMODE" 512)` - which make points will be on the line

`(command "_POINT" coordinates)` which will draw the point
The result will also depend on format of coordinates in the file. Expected is 2 or 3 coordinates separated by `,` and decimal should be separated by `.` I don't remember, but maybe it depends on You local settings.